# UI Label is going out of screen when using in tableview in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, ios-autolayout

When text size increase label of cell is going out of the screen.number of line is already 0 but still not working well:

[image]

if i am giving leading constraint then the box is showing full width even if the text is small...box width should be according to the size of the text:

[image]

Comment: Please share your code for the cell.

Comment: Seems like the cell doesn't have a leading constraint

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your label has all its constraints. It seems as though you are missing a leading constraint. If you have all your constraints and set the number of lines to 0 it should not expand past the view.

[image]

Comment: if i am giving leading constraint then the box is showing full width even if the text is small...box width should be according to the size of the text.

Comment: @hassanshahid make it an "Greater Than or Equal" constraint